# Assign a register value from d.in to a local variable

Tags: debugging, trace32, lauterbach

I want to assign a register value to a local macro/variable in trace32.

```
&temp = d.in 0x0234567
```

does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is "d.in"? A member of a class or struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PRACTICE function REGISTER(*regname*) to get the value of a **core register**.

E.g. To assign the value of core register r5 to the macro &temp you can write:

```
&temp=REGISTER(r5)
```

If you try to to the same with a **memory mapped peripheral register** try PRACTICE function Data.Long(*address*).

E.g. To assign the value of 32-bit data mapped to memory address 0x010000 to the macro &temp you can write:

```
&temp=Data.Long(D:0x010000)
```